# SpringBoot @RequestMapping without using JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I was making a Spring Boot application with JPA as at the time it required a database. I no longer need a database, so I removed MsSQL and JPA from my project as well as the repo. I am not receiving any errors when I run my code, but now anytime that I go to the mapped URL it gives me the /error page. Before, when I had JPA, there were no issues and it worked as it should when a user went to the mapped URL via a button on my homepage. Any help or ideas with this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Controller

```
package me.thisGuy.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class FitController {
    /*@Autowired
    myRepo repo;*/

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";

    }
@RequestMapping("/clickMe")
    public ModelAndView change(Model model) {
        ModelAndView chapterView = new ModelAndView();
        List<String> chapterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            chapterView.setViewName("view.jsp");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            chapterView.setViewName("home.jsp");
            // print stack System.out.println(e);
        }
        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\XMLTest");

        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                chapterList.add("'" + file.getName() + "'");
            }
        }
        chapterView.addObject("chapters", chapterList);
        return chapterView;
    }

}
```

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>me.thisGuy</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Fit</name>
    <description>TBD</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.27</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: There is `model` as argument. Why? You don't use it.

Comment: So, what does the error page say? What do your server logs say?

Comment: @JBNizet "Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Dec 19 12:14:56 EST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"

Comment: So you get a 404 Not Found. What is the address you have in your browser location bar? What happens when you add a System.out.println() call in the method supposed to be invoked? Is it printed in the server console? And if you put a System.out.println() call in the constructor of your controller, is it printed in the server console? How do you deploy/run this application? How have you configured JSPs?